# How to know which screen has been shared by getDisplayMedia()

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I am creating a screen sharing application using WebRTC in javascript.
When sharing a screen in Chrome, you can select the window to be shared, and I would like to keep a log of which screen has been shared.

Screen sharing is done as follows.

```
​​​const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true });
});
stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
 shareScreenPeerConnection.addTrack(track, shareScreenStream);
});
```

When I checked the contents of the added track, it was displayed as shown in the attached image. I thought I could identify it by "label", but "window:197:0" does not allow me to determine which window was shared.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5S83.png)

How can I identify the name of an application such as "Firefox", "Finder", "Notepad", etc.?
If you know anything about this, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: you can not do that for privacy reasons.

Comment: I understood. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const displaySurface = videoTrack.getSettings().displaySurface;
    if (displaySurface === 'monitor') {
      setShowScreenshareWarning(true);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**